# Alternate colors of data from two lists?

Tags: list

I'm extracting data from two lists (a Questions list and an Answers list) and am displaying them as question on one line, then answer on the other, and then it repeats, all in one Label. I want the questions in one color, and the answers in one color. If it was in tabular form, it would be easier, but I'm not sure how to do that either. Is it possible? And if so, how?
This is the code that I have so far:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < jobQuestionnaires.Count; index++)
        {
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + jobQuestionnaires[index]["QuestionText"];
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + answers[index]["Answer"];
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the place of Label1, add following markup

```
<table id="tableQuestions" runat="server" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
</table>
```

Modify for loop as follows

```
HtmlTableCell question = new HtmlTableCell();
question.InnerText = "Question & Answer";
question.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontStyle, "bold");
question.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "#b8d1f3");
HtmlTableCell answer = new HtmlTableCell();
//answer.InnerText = "Answer";
//answer.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontStyle, "bold");
//answer.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "#b8d1f3");

HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
row.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "100%");
row.Cells.Add(question);
//row.Cells.Add(answer);
tableQuestions.Rows.Add(row);

for (int index = 0; index < jobQuestionnaires.Count; index++)
{
    HtmlTableRow r = new HtmlTableRow();
    question = new HtmlTableCell();
    question.InnerText = jobQuestionnaires[index]["QuestionText"].ToString();
    question.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontStyle, "bold");
    question.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "gray");
    r.Cells.Add(question);
    tableQuestions.Rows.Add(r);

    r = new HtmlTableRow();
    answer = new HtmlTableCell();
    answer.InnerText = answers[index]["Answer"].ToString();
    answer.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "black");
    r.Cells.Add(answer);
    tableQuestions.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

Comment: You only need to replace label.. others are dynamic controls.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Where am I defining _tblTransactions_ ?

Comment: @Adrian sorry typo. Corrected the answer

Comment: Awesome. On another note, it won't let me use _answer_ and _question_ in the for loop because they're already defined on top. If I remove the definition in the for loop, it will only print out the first question and answer.

Comment: @Adrian try the updated code

Comment: Updated code retrieves everything, but there are two minor details that I want to update:
It's displayed as Question - Answer rather than:
Question
Answer
And the div code is showing on the HTML page. If you help fix this, I'm very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18413/discussion-between-amal-hashim-and-adrian).